# Why is there a 'p' in "assumption" but not in "assume"?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, etymology, suffixes, phonology

I know a little bit about the [suffix **-tion**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tion). It is usually added to verbs.

Examples:

> -domination (from dominate),
> -admiration (admire),
> -deviation (deviate),
> -ejection (eject).

***"Exemption (exempt)"*** has a ***'p'*** in the ***'-tion'*** form, because the verb form also has a ***'p'***. ***"Preemption (preempt)"*** also has a ***'p'*** in both forms.

But ***"assumption"*** from ***"assume"***, the verb has no ***'p'***  (like it's not *"assumpt"*) and the noun derived from it has a ***'p'***.

It threw me off while I was thinking of the nouns and verb forms that are related. Why is there a ***'p'*** in ***"assumption"*** but not in ***"assume"***?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Assumption* is directly derived from Latin [**assumptionem**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/assumption) which does have a P, so it also has a P. *Assume* on the other hand is derived from Latin [**assumere**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/assume), which didn't have a P.

Other similar examples include *presume/presumption* and *consume/consumption*

### Articulatory reasons for the P

The epenthetic P is inserted for articulatory reasons.

**Epenthesis** happens for a variety of reasons such as:

- ease of articulation
- to prevent adjacent vowels in a [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)) (e.g. *idea of* being pronounced *idea[**r**]of* in most non-rhotic accents)
- to simplify consonant clusters (some people—mostly non-native speakers who don't have complex clusters in their native language—pronounce words like *screen, scratch, school* with a preceding vowel to break the consonant cluster).

#### Epenthetic stops between nasals and fricatives

There are many situations where epenthetic consonants are inserted. Most of the time when there's a voiceless fricative (/s ʃ θ/ etc) after a nasal (/m n ŋ/), we tend to insert an epenthetic stop (/p t k/ etc) between both the fricative and a nasal.

Here's a good explanation from [*English after RP* by Geoff Lindsey](https://books.google.com/books/about/English_After_RP.html?id=6nSKDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y):

> The /n/ is a stop sound, which means that the oral airflow of speech is stopped; the tongue blade is held against the alveolar ridge while breath is re-directed through the nose. As /n/ changes to /s/ [which is an oral consonant i.e the air comes out through the mouth], airflow must be switched from nasal to oral, and at the same time the stoppage at the alveolar ridge must be released,
>
> [...]
>
> Epenthesis is more likely if the fricative after the nasal is voiceless, when the articulatory system has an additional voicing change to handle [i.e. moving from a voiced sound like /n/ to a voiceless one like /s/]. It’s less likely if the fricative is at the beginning
> of a stressed syllable, e.g. *inˈsane* [not **in[t]sane*].

(pp 63-64)

This phenomenon is called [epenthesis (excrescence)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis)

The same thing happened to *assumption* in Latin before it entered English (as Colin Fine explained). There's a voiceless fricative /ʃ/ after a nasal /m/, so when changing from nasal to oral, Latin speakers put an epenthetic stop /p/ (homorganic with the nasal) between the nasal and the fricative.

There are many examples of epenthetic stops in present day English:

- *youngster* is usually pronounced *young[**k**]ster*, (with an epenthetic *k* between the nasal [ŋ] and the oral fricative [s])
- *warmth* and *hamster* are often pronounced *warm[**p**]th* and *ham[**p**]ster*, respectively (with an epenthetic p)
- *thun**d**er* used to be *þunor*, the d is epenthetic.
- In some English accents, *wants* and *once* are pronounced identically i.e. 'once' with an epenthetic t ([from another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/263757/106592)).

Comment: also consume/consumption?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yeah.

Answer (score 18):

Void's answer give the immediate explanation: English does it because Latin does it. **Edit** - and now also explains the phonetic reason.

But there is a more general answer behind this. It's a phenomenon called [epenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) (not a very good article, but it gives the idea): where a sound comes to be inserted between two other sounds, just because it starts happening by accident, and sometimes becomes standard.

Latin speakers (before the time of Classical Latin) came to pronounce historical **sum-si* and **sum-tom* as *sumpsi* and *sumptom* (classical *sumptum*) simply because, in moving the mouth from /m/ to /s/ or /t/, if the timing went a bit awry, a /p/ would just "happen".

Almost the same thing happened in the English word *thimble*: in Old English it was *þȳmel* ("thymel").

Comment: and English *empty*.